# Firebase security for things like indexes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm looking at using firebase for a small project, but one stumbling block I can't find an answer to is that of security as it relates to things like indexes for a purely client side application.

For example, if I need an index for articles -- that is, not using priority -- for alternate sorting, how would I secure this?

The client would need access to the list that contains the article ids sorted appropriately, which as far as I can tell also means the client can then be malicious and completely reorder or delete that index, not just the article it posted.

For that matter, the same goes for setting priority, or really any kind of auxiliary data that is automatic and not user entered - a change date for example.

Am I missing something? Or are you forced to have a server component to accomplish that level of data security/integrity?

**Edit**: The simplest case of this I can think of, is something like a date created field on an article - What prevents the client from just setting that maliciously?

Comment: You would need to detail a specific use case outlining what a user can and cannot do, in order to provide examples, but you can certainly secure to some degree how the index can be manipulated. For starters, you can prevent them from modifying any record in the index other than their own, just as you do for the articles.

Comment: Edited the question with the simplest possible case I can think; Tampering with something as simple as a date created. While that would only affect the article itself, if you use that field for sorting, now you can tamper with a sorted index.